# Prove that every idempotent element is not nilpotent element.

Tags: abstract-algebra, idempotents

Let $R$ be a ring. Prove that every idempotent element is not nilpotent element.

I've got a problem with proving this question. I was be grateful, if somebody would be help me.

Comment: Every nonzero idempotent is not nilpotent ($0$ is both idempotent and nilpotent). It is a really straightforward application of the definitions. Idempotent means $x^2=x$. Nilpotent means $x^n=0$ for some $n\geq 1$.

Answer (score 2):

Definitions: if $x\in R$ and $R$ is a ring, then we say that an element is **idempotent** if $x^2 = x$, and **nilpotent** if for some $n\in\mathbb N: x^n=0$.

Now, suppose that $x$ is non-zero and idempotent. Note that $x^3 = x x^2 = xx = x^2 = x$.  What can we say in general about $x^n$?

Comment: Can be this proof corect?

Comment: "Let $a\in R$ be a non-zero idempotent element, so $a^2 = a$. Now, assume that $a$ is also a nilpotent  element, then we have $0 = a^2 = a$, a contradiction.

Comment: Not quite.  If $a$ is nilpotent, it isn't necessarily true that $a^2=0$. Replace $2$ with the right number.

Comment: So I thing, this answer can be ture. "Let $a\in R$ be a non-zero idempotent element, so $a^2 = a$. Now, assume that $a$ is also a nilpotent element, then $a^n = 0$ for some positive integer. Hence we have $$0 = a^n = a^{n-2} a^2 = a^{n-2} a = a^{n-1}$$ a contradiction." Is this proof correct?

Comment: Well, that's not quite what I had in mind but it works, almost.  You just have to replace "$a^n=0$ for some positive integer" with "let $n$ be the smallest integer so that $a^n=0$". Otherwise, $a^{n-1}$ could be equal to zero after all. And you're welcome.

Comment: What I had expected you to notice, in case you were wondering, is that for any positive integer $n$: if $x$ is idempotent, then $x^n=x$ (you could prove this inductively through steps identical to those of your proof). From there, it's clear that if $x$ is non-zero and $x$ is idempotent, clearly $x^n=x$ is non-zero as well. That being said, I find the proof you discovered to be more elegant.

Comment: I'm really grateful